# Trying to connect to Sphinx Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, sphinx

I trying to connect to Sphinx Windows Service localhost. I have installed the service and it is running, I have built an index correctly and I am using a .net Sphinx Client to try and connect: https://code.google.com/p/sphinx-dotnet-client/

```
         ConnectionBase _connection;
         _connection = new PersistentTcpConnection("localhost", 9312);

        try
        {

            _connection.Open();
            var command = new SearchCommand(_connection, new SearchQuery("garcia"));
            command.Execute();
        }
        finally
        {
            _connection.Close();
        }
```

I am getting the error:
**"An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"**

This is the default port for Sphinx according to there documentation:
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#quick-tour

I am at a loss on how to debug this and what step to take next.

Comment: It may be the default port, but it still has to match wat is setup in sphinx.conf. And searchd service has to actully be running. And firewall(s) has to be setup to allow connections. Have you checked all that?